# Scale color of lines based on frequency of path

Tags: r, ggplot2, data-visualization

I am attempting to map out the paths that people take with their engagement with our marketing content.

I have data on all marketing engagements (links clicked, etc), their 'marketing channel', and their 'engagement position".

Engagement position are the following: first touch [first time they ever engage with us], lead create [when they form-fill and give us enough info], opportunity create [the engagement that happened right before an opportunity was created], and closed won [the engagement that happened right before they signed and purchased].

I was successful actually mapping the paths, but the problem is with 14 channels and 100k+ individual paths, the resulting chart is very much unreadable.

For this reason, i want to scale the color of the lines based on the frequency of the occurrence of the entire path.

This is the format i have data in:

```
______________________________
| id  |  channel  | position |
| 1   | direct    | FT       |
| 1   | SEM       | LC       |
| 1   | email     | OC       |
| 1   | video     | CW       |
| 2   | SEM       | FT       |
| 2   | Video     | LC       |
| 2   | Event     | OC       |
| 2   | Email     | CW       |
______________________________
```

So i want to have the graph have the Y axis be position, X axis be the channel, and then scale the color of each individual path (identified by the ID) depend on the frequency of the entire path. so i dont want it to show me what is the most common FT to LC, then the most common LC to OC, etc--i want it to show the most common full path.

here's an example of what the data looks like with my current code:

[image: map picture]

this was created using this code:

```
ggplot(tblp, aes(x=position, y=channel, group=id)) +
geom_line(alpha=.01, size=.5)
```

so now all i need to do is figure a way to vary the color scale based on the frequency of the entire path. Would this require a different setup of data frame?

any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Your data is currently structured so that each point on a path is a row; to gauge the frequency of paths, you'll need to reshape your data so that each entire path is a row, then join the summarized data back to your current data format on `id`. This is made pretty easy with `tidyr::spread` and some `dplyr` operations.

```r
library(tidyverse)

tb <- tribble(~id, ~channel, ~position
              , 1, "direct", "FT"
              , 1, "SEM", "LC"
              , 1, "email", "OC"
              , 1, "video", "CW"
              , 2, "SEM", "FT"
              , 2, "Video", "LC"
              , 2, "Event", "OC"
              , 2, "Email", "CW"
              , 3, "SEM", "FT"
              , 3, "Video", "LC"
              , 3, "Event", "OC"
              , 3, "Email", "CW")

spread_tb <- tb %>% spread(position, channel)

spread_tb
#> # A tibble: 3 x 5
#>      id    CW     FT    LC    OC
#> * <dbl> <chr>  <chr> <chr> <chr>
#> 1     1 video direct   SEM email
#> 2     2 Email    SEM Video Event
#> 3     3 Email    SEM Video Event

to_plot <-
  spread_tb %>%
  group_by(FT, CW, LC, OC) %>%
  summarise(n = n()) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  right_join(spread_tb, by = c("FT", "CW", "LC", "OC")) %>%
  select(n, id) %>%
  right_join(tb, by = 'id')

to_plot
#> # A tibble: 12 x 4
#>        n    id channel position
#>    <int> <dbl>   <chr>    <chr>
#>  1     1     1  direct       FT
#>  2     1     1     SEM       LC
#>  3     1     1   email       OC
#>  4     1     1   video       CW
#>  5     2     2     SEM       FT
#>  6     2     2   Video       LC
#>  7     2     2   Event       OC
#>  8     2     2   Email       CW
#>  9     2     3     SEM       FT
#> 10     2     3   Video       LC
#> 11     2     3   Event       OC
#> 12     2     3   Email       CW

ggplot(to_plot, aes(x=position, y=channel, group=id, color = n)) +
  geom_line()
```

[image]

Comment: legendary! i'll give this a shot and report back--looks like it should be exactly what i need!

Comment: is there a way to also vary the opacity on the frequency?

Comment: Add alpha as to your aesthetic mapping; from the code above, `aes(..., alpha = n)`